# Transferring files through Java NIO APIs

Tags: java, networking, io, nio, file-transfer

I'm trying to transfer an mp3 file from Server to Client using Java NIO APIs.

In particular, I am trying to use transferTo & transferFrom methods.

I've already checked that the server recognizes the file appropriately and transfers to a FileChannel.

However, in the point of view of the client, it considers that the size of the FileChannel connected to the server is 0 which can be interpreted that the client did not receive any files from the channel.

Here are the results on the consoles of both server and client.

[Server]

```
Server is started...

java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:7777 remote=/127.0.0.1:60430]Here comes a new client!

!!write activated!!

Channel size : 3622994
filename : C:\Users\InhoKim\Music\5 O'clock - Black Nut.mp3
java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:7777 remote=/127.0.0.1:60430]The number of files transferred :  1
```

[Client]

```
!!read activated!!
Channel size : 0
```

How do I have to solve this problem?

Here are the full codes of both server and client

[Server]

```
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.channels.SelectableChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Set;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class MusicServer {
    private Selector selector = null;
    private ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = null;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    File dir = new File("C:\\Users\\InhoKim\\Music\\");
    boolean test = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MusicServer ms = new MusicServer();
        ms.initServer();
        ms.startServer();
    }

    public void initServer() {
        try {

            selector = Selector.open();
            serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
            serverSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false); 
            serverSocket = serverSocketChannel.socket();
            InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 7777);
            serverSocket.bind(isa); 
            serverSocketChannel.register(selector,  SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT); 

        } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    }

    public void startServer() {

        System.out.println("Server is started...");

        try {
            while (true) {
                selector.select();

                Set<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys();
                for (SelectionKey key : keys) {

                    SelectableChannel channel = key.channel();

                    if (channel instanceof ServerSocketChannel) {
                        if (key.isAcceptable())
                            accept(key);
                    } else {
                        if (key.isWritable()) {
                            if(test)
                                write(key);
                        }

                    }
                }   
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    }

    private void accept(SelectionKey key) { 
        ServerSocketChannel server = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();

        try {
            SocketChannel sc = server.accept();
            if (sc == null) return;
            sc.configureBlocking(false);
            sc.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE); 
            System.out.println(sc.toString() + "Here comes a new client!");

        } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    }
    private void write(SelectionKey key) {
        if(test)
        System.out.println("!!write activated!!");
        test = false;

        SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
        try {

            File[] files = dir.listFiles();

            int count = 0;
            for (File file : files) {
                count++;
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                FileChannel inChannel = fis.getChannel();
                System.out.println("Channel size : " + (int)inChannel.size());
                System.out.println("filename : " + file);

                inChannel.transferTo(0, (int)inChannel.size(), sc);

                fis.close();
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(sc.toString() + "The number of files transferred :  " + count);

        } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();} 
    }   
}
```

[Client]

```
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.util.Set;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class MusicClient {
    private Selector selector = null;
    private SocketChannel sc = null;
    int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MusicClient mc = new MusicClient();
        mc.startServer();
    }

    public void initServer() {

        try {
            selector = Selector.open();
            sc = SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 7777)); 
            sc.configureBlocking(false);
            sc.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);

        } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    public void startServer() {
        initServer();
        startReader();
    }

    public void startReader() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                selector.select();

                Set<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys();

                for (SelectionKey key : keys) {
                    if (key.isReadable()) {
                        read(key);
                        System.exit(0);

                    }
                }
            }

        } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    private void read(SelectionKey key) {
        System.out.println("!!read activated!!");
        SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
        try {

        File dir = new File("D:\\Target2\\");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dir + "\\" + count + ".mp3"); // file name has been set as a number
        count++;
        FileChannel outChannel = fos.getChannel();
        System.out.println("Channel size : " + (int)outChannel.size());
        outChannel.transferFrom(sc, 0, (int)outChannel.size());
        fos.close();    

        } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> in the point of view of the client, it considers that the size of the FileChannel connected to the server is 0

There is no such thing as a '`FileChannel` connected to the server'. File channels are connected to files. What you have is a `FileChannel` connected to a new `FileOutputStream` which has just created a new file, whose size is therefore zero.

> which can be interpreted that the client did not receive any files from the channel.

No, it can be interpreted as you telling the `FileChannel` to transfer zero bytes, which it did correctly.

You can't get the size of a `SocketChannel`, because it doesn't mean anything (consider a peer that just keeps sending and never closes the connection). So in this case you have to use `Long.MAX_VALUE` as the size. The transfer will complete when there are no more bytes to be transferred, or indeed before, especially as you are using non-blocking mode.

**EDIT** I don't see any reason to use non-blocking mode in the client. I would remove that, and the `Selector.` And `transferFrom()` must be called in a loop that terminates when it returns zero. Using `transferTo()` in the server is considerably more complex if you must use non-blocking mode there, as you have to register `OP_WRITE` when it returns zero and re-select and restart using an adjusted offset when you get it, and deregister `OP_WRITE` if it doesn't return zero.

Comment: I modified the 'transferFrom' method in the Client to :
outChannel.transferFrom(sc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);

And now the file transferred to the Client contains several information such as title, running time, artist, etc.

However, I cannot play it longer than 24 seconds... it shuts down after 24 seconds.

I guess this problem has occurred because I did not use any loop around the transferFrom and transferTo methods.

So... How should the loop look like? I mean... how can I check if there is or isn't data remaining on the SocketChannel?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It helped me a lot! 
Because I don't have enough knowledge about Blocking and Selector, I have just tried adding a loop around transferFrom and To methods.
The file transferred successfully and I checked it has a proper file size, title, artist and running time (about 3:46) but it still keeps closed after playing for 24 seconds...
Is this problem related to the concepts of Blocking & Selector?
If so, I'd rather study more about NIO first...

Comment: It is extremely rare for a client to have any use for non-blocking I/O, and unless your client is connecting to thousands of servers at the same time this isn't one of them.